# LaTeX math expression in knitr kable (Sweave)

Tags: r, knitr, sweave

Is it possible and how to use a LaTeX math expression in a knitr/Sweave report with `kable`? In the example below, `$x^2$` is rendered "as is".

With `xtable`, for the example below, I would use the option `sanitize.colnames.function = function(x) x` of `print.xtable`. Is there such an option for `kable`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

<<>>=
library(knitr)
dat <- mtcars[1:5,1:5]
options(knitr.table.format = "latex")
@

<<results='asis'>>=
names(dat)[1] <- "$x^2$"
kable(dat, booktabs=TRUE, caption="My table")
@

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, use the option `escape=FALSE`:

```
kable(dat, booktabs = TRUE, caption = "My table", escape = FALSE)
```

Comment: Notice that for backslashes you need both to double them and then use `escape=FALSE`. So for example you would put `$\\le 5$` in your table, and then call `kable` with `escape=FALSE` parameter to render `≤ 5`

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, use this:**

```
names(dat)[1] <- "$x^{2}$"
```

this might also help you sometime:

```
names(df) <- c("$\\lambda_1$", "$\\lambda_2$","$\\lambda_3$" )
```

the result is the same of:

```
names(df) <- c("$λ_{1}$", "$λ_{2}$", "$λ_{3}$")
```