# How to let bookdown render LaTeX in kableExtra table headers properly?

Tags: r, latex, kableextra

I use `kableExtra` package in `rmarkdown` (`bookdown`) to generate nice looking tables in pdf outputs. All works well except for the rendering of LaTeX code in headers. A header named like `$\\alpha$` isn't rendered as the Greek alpha. The result is just a  `$\alpha$` shown in the pdf document.

Additional information: I use `format = "latex"` and `escape = TRUE`. If I use `escape = FALSE`, I get an error when rendering the document:

```
I was unable to find any missing LaTeX packages from the error log _main.log.
! Misplaced \noalign.
\cmidrule ->\noalign 
                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@ifnextchar [{\@cmidrule }{\@cmidrule ...
l.1293 \cmidrule
                {3-7}
```

I am sorry for not giving a reproducible example. I somehow hope it is a setting I missed somewhere in the `kableExtra`. If it is needed I will make an example though.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create table in rmarkdown using greek letters in column headers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50046055/how-to-create-table-in-rmarkdown-using-greek-letters-in-column-headers)

Comment: @bttomio i found the same solution, but it didn't work for my. unfortenately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

````
---
title: "Use slashes to escape"
author: "bttomio"
date: "3/24/2021"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

```{r echo=F}
library(kableExtra)
x <- matrix(1:4, ncol=2)
kbl(x, col.names=c('$\\alpha$', 'B'), align = 'c', 'latex', booktabs = T, escape = F) %>%
    add_header_above(c("$\\\\alpha$" = 2), escape = F)
```
````

-output

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach! But what if I don't want an extra header row? So the alpha symbol on the place of A

Comment: I edited my answer to also show alpha in the place of A. Thanks.

Comment: yess, it works... in your code, not in mine. Since I didn't give a reproducible example, I will accept this answer. I will do more research in my own code.

Comment: It may be related to the set up of the column names before the `kbl` function, e.g. in a `data.frame` object.

Comment: yes, that should be the case! Thank you for pointing me in that direction. Now I am trying to find a way to solve that.

Comment: well, it is very strange, my code doesn't recognize the $ signs as having LaTeX code in between them.

Comment: Leave the column names as the last step, just before the `kbl` function. This might fix it.

Comment: the data frames I use already have names, obviously, names like `$\\alpha$`. If remove the names and add them later, the result is still the same. I will try to make a reproducible example.

Comment: Are they between quotes (i.e. `"$\\alpha$"`)?

Comment: if I add `format = "pandoc"` instead of `"latex"`the LaTeX coded column names are properly rendered, but then the rest of the `kbl` parameters don't do anything. It keeps me wondering....

Comment: I see. It's hard to guess. Maybe the error message is coming from somewhere else.